# Gitlab CI emulator not starting

Tags: docker, android-emulator, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem with the CI on GitLab. It was working before and then, few days ago without changing anything it stopped to work. The emulator doesn't start anymore and the job always finish in timeout.

Here are the logs of the job when it fails ([full log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oEReGOMq0lEIIi3BE7KdfjtcR1TUjQ1P/view?usp=sharing)):

```
[ ... ]

$ wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
$ chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
$ android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update > update.log
Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
$ android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "emulator" "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};google_apis;x86_64"  > installEmulator.log
Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
$ echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name test --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};google_apis;x86_64"
Loading local repository...                                                     
[=========                              ] 25% Loading local repository...       
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no] $ android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd test -no-window -no-audio &
$ ./android-wait-for-emulator
statvfs('/root/.android/avd/test.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory
Waiting for emulator to start
Pulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-577f813d ...
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

Here are the logs of the EXACT SAME job when it worked ([full log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uWW1gKa4-JfYnQ6Q-v43mteCJ7Yd5sHG/view?usp=sharing)):

```
[ ... ]

$ wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
$ chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
$ android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update > update.log
Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
$ android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "emulator" "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};google_apis;x86_64"  > installEmulator.log
Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
$ echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name test --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};google_apis;x86_64"
Loading local repository...                                                     
[=========                              ] 25% Loading local repository...       
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...        
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no] $ android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd test -no-window -no-audio &
$ ./android-wait-for-emulator
statvfs('/root/.android/avd/test.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory
Waiting for emulator to start
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
 - Click "OK"

Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
emulator: INFO: boot completed
emulator: INFO: boot time 23881 ms
emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
Emulator is ready
$ adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
$ adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
$ adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
$ adb shell input keyevent 82
$ cd ./DenisAppProject
$ ./gradlew connectedCheck

[ ... ]

$ adb emu kill
OK: killing emulator, bye bye
OK
emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 146931 ms
Job succeeded
```

And here is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
    image: openjdk:8-jdk

    variables:
      ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
      ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
      ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"
      EMULATOR_VERSION: "26"

    before_script:
      - apt-get --quiet update --yes
      - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
      - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
      - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
      - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
      - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
      - chmod +x ./DenisAppProject/gradlew
      # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
      - set +o pipefail
      - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
      - set -o pipefail

    stages:
      - build
      - unit-test
      - instrumental-test

    lintDebug:
      tags: ["android"]
      stage: build
      script:
        - cd DenisAppProject/
        - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :DenisApp:lintDebug -PbuildDir=lint

    assembleDebug:
      tags: ["android"]
      stage: build
      script:
        - cd DenisAppProject/
        - ./gradlew assembleDebug
      artifacts:
        paths:
        - DenisApp/build/outputs/

    debugTests:
      tags: ["android"]
      stage: unit-test
      script:
        - cd DenisAppProject/
        - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :DenisApp:testDebug

    instrumentation_tests:
      tags: ["android"]
      stage: instrumental-test
      script:
        - apt-get --quiet update --yes
        - apt-get --quiet install --yes libx11-dev libpulse0 libgl1 libnss3 libxcomposite-dev libxcursor1 libasound2
        - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
        - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
        - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update > update.log
        - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "emulator" "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};google_apis;x86_64"  > installEmulator.log
        - echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name test --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};google_apis;x86_64"
        - android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd test -no-window -no-audio &
        - ./android-wait-for-emulator
        # Turn off animations
        - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
        - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
        - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
        - adb shell input keyevent 82
        - cd ./DenisAppProject
        - ./gradlew connectedCheck
        - adb emu kill
```

Screen of the job where you can see that it worked the first time and then it stopped (all the jobs before were working). [image: Screen]

Answer (score 1):

@Denis-Pinna
Hi, I tried to set gitlab CI first time. I am getting following error when ii start the emulator after creation.

Waiting for emulator to start
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm
More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I reproduced the same environment locally with docker. Then I could try to start the emulator with logs and I found out that I had a segmentation fault error, after some other tests I found that taking the normal emulator version and not the 64 one solved my problem, I also added some parameters as disabling the gpu, the starting animation etc. It doesn't explain why it suddenly stopped to work but at least this command work :

```
- android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd test -no-boot-anim -no-snapshot-save -no-audio -no-window -gpu off -debug  -all
```

and use the emulator image

`system-images;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK};google_apis_playstore;x86`

Comment: Hi Denis, so did the x86 emulator image also work in the GitLab CI? 
Or did this image only work in your local environment?